# Invalid template

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to send sms ,i am getting like this

> {"errors":[{"code":80,"message":"Invalid template"}],"status":"failure"}

my code is:

```
def sending_sms(number,message):

   url = 'http://api.textlocal.in/send/'
   msg = message
   post_fields=({"username":"*********","password":"******","numbers":number,"message":msg})
   request = Request(url, urlencode(post_fields).encode())
   print request
   json = urlopen(request).read().decode()
   print json
   return json
```

Comment: How is this question related to django? You can use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library for this.

Comment: ok,thank you for your suggestion,how to solve that error

Comment: You should study the [api documentation](http://api.textlocal.in/docs/) of the service you are using. As far as i can see this error is undocumented. So it's hard to guess why your request fails. But their [python example](http://api.textlocal.in/docs/sendsms) has a `?` at the end of the url. Like this `"http://api.textlocal.in/send/?"`

Answer (score 0):

The [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) is easy to use for this kind of task.

```
import requests


def sending_sms(number,message):
    url = 'http://api.textlocal.in/send/'

    post_fields = {
        "username": "*********",
        "password": "******",
        "numbers": number,
        "message": message
    }

    response = requests.post(url, data=post_fields)

    json = response.json()
    print json

    return json
```

Comment: i am facing same problem